# Change iOS simulator keyboard layout to match Macbook keyboard

Tags: ios, ios-simulator

I have a Macbook with an Azerty (French) keyboard.
Whenever I start the iOS simulator, the default keyboard layout is Qwerty (Dutch), so when I am typing using the physical hardware keyboard of my macbook, some keys (A,Z,M,...) do not match.
The setting `Hardware > Keyboard > iOS Uses Same Layout` as OSX is enabled.
I know how to change the keyboard settings in when going to the Settings app on the simulator, but the setting is forgotten every time the simulator is restarted (which happens very often when switching between different simulators), so this is a real PITA.
Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"iOS Uses Same Layout" is not very accurate as there's no real way to perfectly proxy the layout between the two very different (at this level of the stack) systems.  It uses a "best guess" and will tell iOS to switch to the keyboard associated with the *language* of your host keyboard.

If you toggle between French/Azerty and Dutch/Qwerty, the simulator will tell the hosted runtime "french" and "english".  You need to select "Azerty" as your French layout and Qwerty as your Dutch layout from iOS's keyboard preferences (for each device).

Comment: Thanks I know that. What I would wish is to not always needing to go to the settings app, add a French Azerty keyboard and toggle to that keyboard whenever the simulator is restarted. By default my simulator has 3 keyboards enabled: English, Emoji and Dutch, which is the default selected keyboard (which to me does not make sense -> my MacOS locale is UK English and my keyboard is French Azerty, so where the does this Dutch keyboard comes from?)

Comment: Odd.  Sorry, I read your question too quickly.  Do this: 'grep CoreSimulatorBridge ~/Library/Logs/CoreSimulator/*/system.log'.  You should see some lines like "Switching to keyboard:..." and "KEYMAP: Chose mode=en_US@hw=US;sw=QWERTY from match=en_US@hw=US;sw=QWERTY from language=en" ... what do they say for your case?

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me on this. This is what I see: KEYMAP: Chose mode=nl_NL@hw=Dutch;sw=QWERTY from match=nl_NL@hw=Dutch;sw=QWERTY from language=nl. The thing is that I have no idea why it seems to always be wanting to select nl as language. My OS X (10.9) is in English, and my region settings are set on UK...

Comment: Actually, I found what the issue was. My Macbook keyboard layout was set to Belgian (which is exactly the same layout as the French Azerty keyboard). For some very bizarre reason the simulator thinks that this should be NL language with Qwerty keyboard. I changed my Macbook keyboard layout to French, and now it works perfectly (the simulator shows FR/Azerty keyboard first by default). I shall though report this as a bug to Apple.

Comment: I can save you the trouble as the report will just get routed to me, and it'll be duped to another radar we have open to figure out a better way of matching up the two very different keyboard systems.

Comment: That would be great! Thanks for this. I had also posted an entry on the Apple developer forum (https://devforums.apple.com/thread/247189). I guess, the issue here is that the simulator asssumes that Belgian keyboard means Dutch language, which in turn means Dutch/Qwerty keyboard. This is where it goes wrong as the "Belgian" keyboard layout is Azerty, and btw in Belgium, half of the people speak Dutch and the other half speaks French, so assuming that Belgian would mean Dutch language is incorrect in 50% of the cases.

Comment: Any update on this? I've got the exact same issue, Belgian speaking Dutch and using Azerty keyboard layout.

Comment: You need to just setup your keyboard in the simulated device's preferences.

Comment: I had the same issue. Mac os x in English with Belgian Azerty keyboard layout. Setting the French azerty on top of the keyboard list in the emulator worked for me.

Comment: @JeremyHuddlestonSequoia Hello Jeremy, I'm having the same problem as Quentin and I was wondering If there was a better way to fix it now, other than changing the Macbook's keyboard. I'm using a Belgian keyboard and I want to have french AZERTY keyboard in the simulator. Thanks!